# what is the command for man open(2)?

Tags: linux-kernel, manpage

what is the command for man open(2)?

when using

```
man open
```

I get the description of OPENVT(1).

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try `man 2 open`. This will look for `open` in section 2 of the manual.